# How to build a layout of photos like facebook shows in android app

Tags: android, layout

I want to build a layout of photos same like facebook uses in it's android app. I want to achieve a layout like below:

I have tried the below using recyclerview to show the photos:

```
  rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (adapter.getItemCount() == 1) {
                return 2;
            } else if (adapter.getItemCount() == 2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (adapter.getItemCount() == 3) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {

                return 1;

            }


        }
    });
```

Now I do not have width and height of images, I am having url only of that image.
So, in the case if I upload 2 images, I want to check if the images are portrait (height is greater the width) or landscape and need to show the images accordingly.

I have used the below code to get the height and width of image:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
             Looper.prepare();
       try {                                                     listItemHolder.imageBitmap = Glide.with(mContext).
                                                                        load(mainImage).                                                                       asBitmap().                                                                    into(-1,-1).
get();
 } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
 } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
 return null;
 }
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {
  }
 }.execute();
```

But the code makes my application too slow.

Can anyone have any idea here, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  StaggeredGridLayoutManager

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

for that

Comment: I am already using this and I have managed the columns of the photos.
the only thing which is remaining is setting the width and height of photos and set span count according to the width and height of photos.

Answer (score 0):

To get image's width and height:

Your code are using glide to load full picture that makes slow.

If you just want to get dimensions, you could use bitmap option.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Just decode it from stream.

Check this [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I want to first calculate width and height from image url and then need to load in imageview.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Get http stream, then using BtimapFractory.decodeStream(InputStream is) to get height and width form options.